# contentsOfDirectoryAtPath optional array index Swift

Tags: arrays, swift, nsdictionary, immutability, option-type

I'm having trouble using an optional dictionary in Swift.
I'm attempting to remove items from a string array which is populated via contentsOfDirectoryAtPath.

Here's a sample:

```
    let rootApplicationSupportArray = fileManager.contentsOfDirectoryAtPath("/Volumes/\(partitionComboBox.stringValue)/Library/Application Support/", error: &error)

            var pointer = 0
        var safePointer = 0
        while pointer < rootApplicationSupport.numberOfItems {
            while safePointer < safeListArray.count {
                if safeListArray[safePointer] == rootApplicationSupportArray[pointer] {rootApplicationSupportArray?.removeAtIndex(pointer)}
                ++safePointer
            }
            ++pointer
        }
```

I'm given error [AnyObject]? does not have a member named 'subscript'

Alternatively, If I define the array as [String] then I get an error "Could not find member 'convertFromStringInterpolationSegmnet'

If I define the array as [AnyObject] I'm then told the array is immutable.

Comment: If you declare you array using let you are declaring it as a constant therefore it will stay like this forever. If you would like to mutate it you have to declare it as var.

Comment: Try not hardcoding your path. String has a method called stringByAppendingPathComponent(). To locate your application support folder you need to use NSSearchPathDirectory.ApplicationSupportDirectory

Comment: Changing let to var was the first step. Should've seen that one.
The code quoted in my question is snippets from two different points in my application. I'm attempting to filter an array of results with another array.

Comment: Do you want to filter the results?

Comment: Are you going to list those files using a tableView ?

Comment: I think it would be much better to store the result as [NSURL]

Comment: They're going into a combobox.

Comment: I can show you how to use array of NSURLs and just display the name of the files without the extension

Comment: The application is intended to list contents of various directories but will not list support items that should not be removed from Library folders.

Comment: Look at how you have to search for your folder at my answer

Comment: You can't assume that the folder will be at that location

Answer (score 1):

`NSFileManager#contentsOfDirectoryAtPath` returns `Optional<[AnyObject]>`; this is not an array itself but is wrapped in an `Optional<T>` box, which either has a `T` value or  nothing. To directly access the methods of `[AnyObject]` you need to unwrap the box by using the `if` statement.

```
let a = NSFileManager.defaultManager().contentsOfDirectoryAtPath(".", error: &error)
if var rootApplicationSupport = a as? [String] {
    for var i = 0; i < rootApplicationSupport.count; ++i {
        if contains(safeListArray, rootApplicationSupport[i]) {
            rootApplicationSupport.removeAtIndex(i--)
        }
    }
    rootApplicationSupport
}
// I assume that `safeListArray` is of `[String]`.
```

In addition, to remove its elements the array has to be mutable. Mutable array can be declared with `var` keyword like as in the code above.

Comment: This answered my question and got me onto the path of solving my issue.

Comment: @MartinPhipps This answered the question so you should click on the checkmark